# Can I force to open datalist below the input?

Tags: html, css

When I use a `<datalist>` with a `<input>`, the list would appear below or above the `<input>` (e.g. if the `<input>` is in the bottom of page, the list will appear above, if the `<input>` is in the top of page, the list will appear below of `<input>`).

Can I force that the list always appear below of `<input>` does not matter the `<input>` position in the page using CSS?

Comment: Any use case for making it open below the input if it is at the bottom? Users will not be able to click all options anyway.

Comment: My example was not so good. I wrote the bottom of page, but suppose that i have a big margin that put the `<input>` a bit below the middle of page.